# Splitting a string and putting it inside a listview

Tags: android, arrays, listview, split

I asked a question before about splitting string but maybe it wasn't clear enough.

I made a simple activity which has an example to what my problem is.

I have a message and it's a long one coming from a server.

I need to split this message and put it inside a listview, I'll show you my code.

```
public class Page1 extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity6);

    String message = "0---12,,,2013-02-12 08:04,,,this is a test,,,0---11,,,2013-02-12 08:05,,,and this is why it is damaged,,,0---10,,,2013-02-12 08:06,,,what comes from select data randomly";

    String[] variables = message.split(",");

    ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView12);
    String[] items = { variables.toString() };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

}

Now let's say that the split is commas ", " so it will be

```
0---12      ------->ID1

2013-02-12 08:04  ------------>date1

this is a test   ----------->subject1

0---11    ------->ID2

2013-02-12 -8:05   ------------>date2

and this is why it is damaged   ----------->subject2
```

And so on, now what I can't do is that I want to put these strings in a loop and write them to a listview such that the subject1 should be in item1 and date1 should be in subitem1 like this

```
Subject1

Date1

------

Subject2

Date2

------
```

This is how the listview should look like

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Tip: If you asked this question before, it may be an option to edit your original question. :)

Comment: what kind of response is that? I sugest you to start using JSON for server - android communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create a custom `ArrayAdapter` to populate a `ListView` from your objects the way you want.

The advantage of this technic is that you gain a Views recycle mechanism that will recycle the `Views` inside you `ListView` in order to spend less memory.

**In Short** you would have to:

**1.** Create  an object that represents your data for a single row.

**2.** Create an `ArrayList` of those objects.

**3.** Create a layout that contains a ListView or add a ListView to you main layout using code.

**4.** Create a layout of a single row.

**5.** Create a `ViewHolder` that will represent the visual aspect of you data row from the stand point of `Views`.

**6.** Create a custom `ArrayAdapter` that will populate the rows according to you needs, in it you will override the `getView` method and use the `position` parameter you receive for the corrent row `View` to indicate the row `index`.

**7.** Finally assign this `ArrayAdapter` to your `ListView` in `onCreate`.

You can get an idea of how to implement this by reading this blog post I wrote:

[Create a Custom ArrayAdapter](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=495)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `ArrayAdaper` is designed for items containing only one single `TextView`. [From the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html):

> A concrete BaseAdapter that is backed by an array of arbitrary objects. By default this class expects that the provided resource id references a single TextView

Consider subclassing `ArrayAdapter` ([docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html)) and override its `getView` method.